# Can I make a scrolledwindow in Glade without a child?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade, scrolledwindow

I have a scrolledwindow as part of an application I've designed in Glade. I don't want to create the child object in Glade though, I want to create it and add it in the code directly.

When I try to do this though, I get a weird result where the whole scrolledwindow is just blank.

[image]

Here I've added a TreeView widget, but the same thing happens if I add a TextView, or presumably something else. You can see the scrollbars on the sides, so I'm sure rows are getting added.

Here's what it looks like when I add a TreeView widget in Glade.

[image]

There's nothing there, because I didn't add anything to it, but it's more like what you'd expect. A blank window.

Is there some setting I'm missing so that I can just leave it childless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if I call `scrolledwindow.hide()` before I add a child, it works. So something like

```
self.scrolled_window = builder.get_object('scrolledwindow1')
self.scrolled_window.hide()
tv = gtk.TreeView()
self.scrolled_window.add(tv)
self.scrolled_window.show_all()
```

will work.

Comment: After I create it but before I add it to the scrolledwindow?

Comment: Before, after, why not try both?